# Teamcity Server Upgrade from 9.1.6 to 10.x

Tags: server, upgrade

I want to upgrade my teamcity server with the manual back-up , I also want to upgrade the DB as well, But not able to succeed. How should i upgrade.

Comment: The upgrade is possible under certain conditions: https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/download/#section=linux-version .

Comment: yes @CelticWarrior , I checked this, I am facing problem for restoring data , I q=want to manually restore and upgrade , but not able to succeed due to mismatch between data and server